# Google Hangout integration needed with proper framework

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, google-hangouts

I have a request where there is teacher and student online learning classroom feature to be developed. I want to integrate online classroom feature with Google Hangout.
I need help to decide which technology among cakephp or laravel or React will be more suitable for the application? 
Also if possible please provide the ideas to integrate google hangout with the application technology.

Comment: "Google will soon be killing Hangouts, the company’s infamous messaging app. 9to5Google reports that the company will be shutting down Hangouts in 2020."